# Xen on Centos 7

Tags: centos, xen

I am a newbie to Xen and want to download it on my machine which currently has CentOS7. I have been researching and experimenting for a couple of days but can't seem to find a straightforward answer on how to install a fully functioning Xen on CentOS7. I tried using the workaround at http://www.lairdscomputer.com/Blog/tabid/62/EntryId/74/Installing-Xen-4-on-Centos-7.aspx, but it seems that some of the packages it uses might be outdated.

Is it even possible to install Xen on CentOS7, even if it is missing some parts to it? Would it be better just to go back to CentOS6.x so that I can install Xen4CentOS?

Thanks in advance! Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Afaik RedHat therefore CentOS is not supporting Xen whoever in fact it is possible.

I am using xen4centos on my Centos7 server, it was installed along with official article from wiki:
https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Xen/Xen4QuickStart

It it is not, please provide some logs, errors etc